# Saving an array to Advanced Custom Fields WordPress

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I'm using the [ACF plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) for WordPress. I'm posting to a custom post type programmatically via my theme. Now, I thought I would be able to save an array of items to a custom field quite easily, but whenever I try to, nothing gets input. I simply get this error when I check the post screen in the admin area:

`Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/lukeseag/public_html/spidr-wp/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/core/fields/text.php on line 127`

Now, I'm kind of throwing this out there for suggestions as to how I can go about solving this problem.

To give some context, I'm programmatically saving data input by a user, and creating a post with it. Much of the data is simple strings and numbers that can each have their own custom field.

But I have an unknown number of `text strings` and `URL's` (with an id number for each) coming through this page too, that need to be linked with the same post. I need to be able to output each set of `text string` and `URL` into their own div on the `single.php` post page. Now, ideally these text/url pairs would be saved in a single array so I can just loop through the array and output the data, but it looks like ACF doesn't want to let this happen?

Any suggestions as to how I can save this data and then output it easily on the `single.php` page? Each set of results will have an `ID` (number), `text string` and `url`.

Thanks!

Comment: Show the code that's producing that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly why all those `"frameworks"` are usually `more pain than gain`. they are designed to look flexible to the lazy but then they always prove useless on a real  case scenario that is a bit more complex than anything that would actually be easily achieved without them.

Anyhow, as for your question.

The problem is that you are passing array instead of a string .
I am not going to go into debugging the plugin, and anyhow , more code and info is needed , so i will just give you ONE possible and easy solution, and that is to compose a `pseudo-array string` like so :

```
'ID|URL|STRING'
```

note that the delimiter pipe (|) is just an example, you could use ( `,` ) ( `:` ) ( `#` ) or whatever.

in other words :

```
$url = 'http://myurl.url/something';
$id = 35;
$string = 'my string';

$pseudo_r = $id . '|' . $url .  '|' . $string . '|'; // results in 'ID|URL|STRING';
```

or you can use the `implode()` function

```
 $pseudo_r = array(
       "url" => $url,
       "id" => $id ,
       "string" => $string
       );

$pseudo_r = implode("|", $pseudo_r); // gives a string
```

and pass it as a string that later on you can decompose it with `explode()`  like so :

```
$pseudo_r = explode( '|', $pseudo_r ); // gives back the original array
```

( Please note that now the array is `NON ASSOCIATIVE` anymore . )

now, since you mentioned that each one of those is a `set`, you can compose the same pseudo array from the sets, using a different delimiter.

This might work for you , but `essentially it is wrong` .

**why is it wrong ?**

Because this is a generic and somewhat *hackish* solution that actually ignores your data type .
You are mixing 3 types of data types , `URL` , `ID` and a `STRING` .
All 3 ( should ) have potentially different validation schemes , and I suspect that the `htmlspecialchars()` part belong to the `URL`.

Another solution is just to find the right data field in the ACF settings or use a different field for each and then just DISPLAY it together , also using the `implode()` and `explode()` functions.

Comment: The only thought you should really consider is not using these frameworks ( namely ACF ) if you want to go a step up in your programming skills...and BTW - Does my avatar really look so masculine ? :-)

Comment: Yea, I've actually decided to make a custom db table and send the results to that, that way I can have them exactly how I want them, without having to be all 'hacky'. haha, I did notice your avatar! But was 10 mins after I posted the comment so wouldn't let me edit, my bad! :P

Answer (score 2):

Yo can save the array using json_encode($your_array) and json_decode() to recover it. This works also for associative arrays.

Comment: Hey there @Mirko ... I'm interested in learning more about your solution, you think you can post some code with your answer to see how that might work? Thanks.